# Why i will get StaticInjectorError in angular 6. what it means

Tags: angular, file-upload, angular6

My Routing Structure

App-> main -> dashboard

I'm trying to implement this `in dashboard.component.ts` but it's showing error below I didn't understand why

Can anyone help me out to get this done?

> core.js:1624 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[DashboardComponent -> FileUploader]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[DashboardComponent -> FileUploader]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for FileUploader!
>   Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[DashboardComponent -> FileUploader]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[DashboardComponent -> FileUploader]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for FileUploader!
>       at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:1034)
>       at resolveToken (core.js:1273)
>       at tryResolveToken (core.js:1218)
>       at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1113)
>       at resolveToken (core.js:1273)
>       at tryResolveToken (core.js:1218)
>       at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1113)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:8168)
>       at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:8856)
>       at resolveDep (core.js:9221)
>       at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:1034)
>       at resolveToken (core.js:1273)
>       at tryResolveToken (core.js:1218)
>       at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1113)
>       at resolveToken (core.js:1273)
>       at tryResolveToken (core.js:1218)
>       at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1113)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:8168)
>       at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:8856)
>       at resolveDep (core.js:9221)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
>       at zone.js:873
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3748)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
>       at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:500)
>       at invokeTask (zone.js:1540)```

Thanks
Surya Teja.K

Comment: post your code here app.module.ts

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FileUploader` service has to be provided - add it to `providers` list of your `AppModule`.

If you don't do that, Angular would not know how to inject an instance of it in your component, and hence, it complains with `NullInjectorError`